# How to change colour in CSS, by giving condition?

Tags: css, colors

I'm having a body. In that there is one field "status". If status=OK background should be white color. If status=error, background should get red. Please tell me how to give the condition in CSS file.

[image: Body code in CSS]

[image: This is the GUI]

Comment: `if (Type.Open == true) {
      //JQUERY CODE TO CHANGE CSS
 }`

I would suggest  jquey for this solution

Comment: Yeah, javascript is the only viable option that you have as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: You still didn't post the html and what is that `status`? is it a javascript variable, object's property or HTML attribute for Body tag?

Comment: status is a field i'm getting from logs. Its not a variable. I dont know much about css. in css file there are lines with background color and text color. I need to change color depending on status field.

Comment: [link]( https://mediafire.com/view/7vgkc542udlutzx/index.html )

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery method to do so. Try the following:

```
var status =  $("[id$=lblStatus]").val()

if(status == "Ok")
{
  $jQuery("body").css("background-color","White");
}
else if (status == "Error")
{
  $jQuery("body").css("background-color","Gray");
}
```

Comment: but how can we achieve this using css instead of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Jquery Code

```
$( "#status" ).change(function() {
   if($(this).val() == "OK")
     {
      $("body").css("background-color","white");
     }
  else 
    {
     $("body").css("background-color","red");
    }
});
```

[Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/swbztgaz/2/)

Comment: Its good... but in my css file its not working. I'll upload my css file.. please tell me where i have to keep the condition.

Comment: Above code need to added in your html page ,with in **script** tag.And don't forget to include first  jquery plugin as `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>`.there is nothing to do with CSS file  @A.N.BAkhilesh