# How to color html table in django based on condition

Tags: html, css, django

How can I color `Class 11` based on those conditions:

- if value > 20 to color to red
- if value > 40 to color orange
- if value > 50 to color green

I searched web and foun only JS ways doing it but I am quite new with JavaScript. I was wondering if there is a way to do it with CSS?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: [How to change colour in CSS, by giving condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838544/how-to-change-colour-in-css-by-giving-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a bunch of if/then/else in the html.

Here's your HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .red {
      color: red;
    }

    .orange {
      color: orange !important;
    }

    .green {
      color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    {% for item in a %}
      {% if item > 50 %}
      <td class="green">{{ item }}</td>
      {% elif item > 40 %}
      <td class="orange">{{ item }}</td>
      {% elif item > 20 %}
      <td class="red">{{ item }}</td>
      {% else %}
      <td>{{ item }}</td>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>B</th>
    {% for item in b %}
      {% if item > 50 %}
      <td class="green">{{ item }}</td>
      {% elif item > 40 %}
      <td class="orange">{{ item }}</td>
      {% elif item > 20 %}
      <td class="red">{{ item }}</td>
      {% else %}
      <td>{{ item }}</td>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the view I created for context:

```py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class View(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({
            'a': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
            'b': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
        })
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```